# SSJS - Retrieve every list a user is on with the status = Active

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs, cloudpage

I am trying to get every list a user is on and having the status="Active".
The script below shows every list a user is found on, but it does not filter by the status="Active".

```
<script runat="server">
  //Initializing
  Platform.Load("core","1");
  var subscriberId = Variable.GetValue('@salesforceId');
  Write("Subscriber Id: "+subscriberId+"<br>");
  var subscriberObject = Subscriber.Init(subscriberId);
  var listArray = subscriberObject.Lists.Retrieve({Property:"Status",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:Active});  
....
```

I also tried:

```
 subscriberObject.Lists.Retrieve({Property:"Status",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"Active"});
```

but it has not shown a difference.

Below is the output of the code:

```
[
 {"List":{"ID":133,"Name":"All Subscribers","Description":"Contains all subscribers","Type":"Private","CreatedDate":"2017-09-24T16:00:52.403"},"CreatedDate":"2018-01-22T05:56:00.000","Status":"Active"}, 
 {"List":{"ID":1920,"Name":"B2B-Acc-ohne-Manager","Description":"","Type":"Private","CreatedDate":"2018-03-15T09:02:55.603"},"CreatedDate":"2018-03-15T09:04:00.000","Status":"Unsubscribed","UnsubscribedDate":"6/12/2018 6:40:00 AM"}, 
 {"List":{"ID":2417,"Name":"Persönliche Mails","Description":"","Type":"Private","CreatedDate":"2018-06-11T09:53:50.293"},"CreatedDate":"2018-06-11T09:56:00.000","Status":"Unsubscribed","UnsubscribedDate":"6/12/2018 6:40:00 AM"}, 
 {"List":{"ID":2419,"Name":"Transaktionsbezogene Mails","Description":"","Type":"Private","CreatedDate":"2018-06-11T10:46:53.437"},"CreatedDate":"2018-06-11T10:48:00.000","Status":"Unsubscribed","UnsubscribedDate":"6/12/2018 6:40:00 AM"}
]
```

Have you an idea filtering the lists?

Comment: I am pretty sure you would need to either filter out via a FOR loop after pulling it via the function OR you would have to utilize the API. That function does not allow a filter.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info that the function does not allow a filter.

But I do not really understand how you would filter out via a for loop.
Can you write an example?

Comment: could do a for loop through the returned array, then a conditional to only do activity if status = active.  Or conditional to add those to a new array. It is pretty heavy processing added in. May be better overall to do API if potential to grow in size.